# Kubernetes: Secrets update but server not rolling out with new env values

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes

I've a Kubernetes cluster running Django on `DEBUG=True` using ConfigMap and some other secrets using K8's secrets. The problem I'm having is that even if I rollout the server it keeps having debug true values, and when I inspect the container, the `env` shows that it's in False.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to solve it?

EDIT:

Here's the `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-app
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: <dockerhub_username>/<image>:latest
          name: backend
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: backend-secret
          - configMapRef:
              name: backend-config
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: gunicorn
```

When I execute `kubectl exec -it my-container -- printenv` it shows the desired value but it seems the server is missing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just figured it out. I mistakenly was recreating secrets to rollout the deployment while the problem was in configmap, I was not reconfiguring it. Thanks @pwoltschk for the help